# Can't cd into directory with space in its name, even with quotes or escaping

Tags: macos, command-line, bash, shell

In a bash shell on a MacOS machine, I can see by typing `ls` that there is a director `Application Support`:

```
$ ls
Accounts                FontCollections     PreferencePanes
Application Scripts     Fonts               Preferences
Application Support     GameKit             Printers
Assistant               Google              PubSub
Assistants              Group Containers    Safari
Audio                   IdentityServices    SafariSafeBrowsing
Caches                  Input Methods       Saved Application State
Calendars               Internet Plug-Ins   Screen Savers
CallServices            Keyboard            Services
ColorPickers            Keyboard Layouts    Sharing
Colors                  KeyboardServices    Sounds
Compositions            Keychains           Spelling
Containers              LanguageModeling    Suggestions
Cookies                 LaunchAgents        SyncedPreferences
CoreFollowUp            Library             VirtualBox
Developer               Logs                Voices
Dictionaries            Mail                WebKit
F5Networks              Messages            com.apple.internal.ck
Family                  Metadata            iMovie
Favorites               Mobile Documents
FileProvider            Passes
```

However, if I trying to `cd` into this directory using either quotes or escape characters as described in [How to cd to a directory that contains a space in its name?](https://superuser.com/questions/256985/how-to-cd-to-a-directory-that-contains-a-space-in-its-name/256986), I still get an error:

```
LM-SJN-21018636:Library kupeek$ cd "Application Support"
-bash: cd: Application: No such file or directory
LM-SJN-21018636:Library kupeek$ cd Application\ Support
-bash: cd: Application: No such file or directory
```

It seems like bash is not 'picking up' the quotes or escape characters and is instead looking for a directory called "Application". Any ideas why this is not working?

Comment: Perhaps you have an alias or similar for `cd` that is badly written. What does `command -v cd` print?

Comment: I would suspect a poorly written function. And I think `command -v cd` from the first comment should be `command -V cd` (capital V); `type -a cd` should also work.

Comment: What happens if you "autofill" it with the Tab-key? Same error?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `cd` may be a poorly defined function or alias. Run `type -a cd` to find out.

A possible alias is explained in [this other answer](https://superuser.com/a/1376516/432690). My answer concentrates on shell functions.

For example if the function used

- `command cd $*` (`command` builtin explained [here](https://superuser.com/a/1376183/432690)) or
- `command cd $@` or
- `command cd $1`

instead of correct

- `command cd "$@"` or
- `command cd "$1"` (not as good as the above, still not fatal)

and your Bash didn't throw `too many arguments` (pre-4.4 version, see [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/373625/108618)), the behavior would be exactly as you described because `Application Support` being a single argument to the function would undergo word splitting inside the function itself, so `command cd` would see `Application` as its first argument.

**If your `cd` is indeed a poorly defined function, you should track the place where it is defined and fix it.** An *ad hoc* solution would be to add the `command` word before `cd`, like this:

```
command cd "Application Support"
```

or

```
command cd Application\ Support
```

(This will also work if alias is the culprit).

Answer (score 1):

Try using more than one set of quotes,

e.g. put the name in single quotes within double quotes:

```
cd "'Application Support'"
```

"An argument enclosed in double quotes presents itself as a single word, even if it contains whitespace separators." [Advanced Bash-Scripting Guide](https://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/quotingvar.html)

Using two sets of quotes (quotes within quotes) is a viable workaround, assuming that the problem here is that the original `cd` command has been aliased. The following definition

```
alias cd='eval command cd'
```

would reproduce the problem reported here (in pre-4.4 version of Bash, see [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/373625)). It happens that `eval` parses the command line for the second time and, on the first pass of parsing, one layer of quoting is removed. Using two sets of quotes works because, removed the first set of quotes, `eval` will pass the argument with the second set of quotes to `cd`.

If such alias is the case, the best solution is to fix it in the first place.

Comment: Simple. I believe the problem here is that the original "cd" command has been aliased. The alias gets the path string as argument and it gets it correctly if you put the first set of quotes. Then it passes it to "cd" but it goes there without quotes and fails. If you put two sets of quotes, the alias gets the string with the first set and then it passes it to "cd" with the second set of quotes and... Magic, it works!

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, I edited my answer and added a reference. I don't have to explain here how to modify a "cd" alias, that would be off-topic. I am answering the question "Any ideas why this is not working?", the answer is because using single quotes alone. Put it within double quotes and it will work.

Answer (score 0):

There could be more blanks or other non-printable chars that you don't see. Try `cd Application*Scrip*` or similar.

Comment: This could be it in some other case, but not in this particular one. Note the message is `-bash: cd: Application: No such file or directory`, not `-bash: cd: Application Support: No such file or directory`. The command doesn't see the whole argument string in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

***IF*** your `cd` isn't a weird alias, then I'd just use <kbd>TAB</kbd> with bash's autocomplete (if it's enabled) to fill a working format for you.

Typing

cd Ap<kbd>TAB</kbd>

looks like it should autofill to something like

```
cd Application\ S
```

(If you do have a weird cd alias, then appending Kamil's answer of typing `command cd A...` should work with TAB's too)

and then wait for you to type more of the wanted name (followed by anoter <kbd>TAB</kbd> to autocomplete the rest). Or just typing <kbd>TAB</kbd> once or twice more will display your available options.

(I'd also not use plain `ls`, but `ls -la` or maybe `ls -1` instead to see only one entry per line, your `ls` output isn't clear)

Comment: This may be a good advice in a general case (i.e. for future users with similar problems) but I doubt it will immediately help the OP. Note the message is `Application: No such file or directory`, not `Application Support: No such file or directory`. If the directory name in the command line simply didn't match the actual name, `cd` would still comply about the whole argument being wrong. I don't downvote answers that may apply to very similar problems, still I'm noting they don't entirely fit the OP's issue and they cannot explain the root of it.

Comment: I thought so too, but it's a little annoying when the title doesn't fully match the real problem ("*My `cd` is broken*"), and tab complete was only mentioned briefly in a comment, so a fuller answer for the "title problem" seemed appropriate.

Answer (score -1):

It's because you're missing by one word. Try using:

```
cd "Application Support GameKit"
```

Comment: I'm repeating myself: This could be it in some other case, but not in this particular one. Note the message is `-bash: cd: Application: No such file or directory`, not `-bash: cd: Application Support: No such file or directory`. The command doesn't see the whole argument string in the first place.

Comment: You mis-read the OP; they're 2 different columns